# Delete element from a iterating list from an event

Tags: c++, list

Wanted to know what is the best way to delete an element from a list which is being iterating continuously in an event loop.
I have an event loop where my list is getting updated

```
for (auto pIt = this->particles.begin(); pIt != this->particles.end(); pIt++) {
    (*pIt)->Update(system, gameTime);
}
```

At a certain event based time I have to remove a random element from the list.
It is handled in a separate function using:

```
this->particles.remove_if([particle](Particle *ptc)->bool {
    return ptc == particle;
});
```

This gives a list iteration runtime error because the iterators in the loop become invalid. What is the optimal way to solve such kind of situation?

Comment: This sounds like you have a concurrent access from multiple threads? In that case you'd need to lock access to the list with a mutex

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: No there is no concurrent across multiple threads. This is a single threaded application. The event loop runs on every frame. At a certain condition the the particle class triggers to be removed. Since it is already being used in event loop, it crashes

Comment: if this is all on one thread then it is not clear how the iterators are supposed to get invalid in this code, you need to post a mcve

Comment: Are you removing particles in `Update`? To be honest that seems like questionable design at best, the quick and dirty solution would be to not use iterators. If it's an `std::list` or something without an `[]` operator then you're probably using the wrong container.

Comment: Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55714723/edit) and correct the code.

Comment: What container do you suggest?

Comment: @AshutoshRautela A vector probably. The thing about a list is the elements can be newd up anywhere in memory, meaning the cpu may have to access ram for each element when iterating. Lists in general are surprisingly and often cripplingly slow to iterate.

Comment: `list::remove_if()` removes all elements that match the predicate. Since the predicate is just a simple pointer comparison, you can use `list::remove()` instead. But, if the pointer is guaranteed to exist in the list only once, use `list::erase()` instead, which returns an `iterator` to the *next* element after the erased element. Use that `iterator` to update the loop's `iterator`, for instance, by having `Update()` return that iterator after it calls `remove(_if)`.

Comment: So you mean the iterator i use to iterate the list in update function, I make it instance variable and use them to erase and update the iterator variable where it is getting deleted right?

Answer (score 0):

The erasing function must have access to the iterator used in the loop (make it a member variable) and if that iterator points to the element being deleted increment the iterator. This way you keep the loop iterator from being invalidated by erasing.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Explosion;

struct Particle {
    void update(Explosion&);
};

struct Explosion {
    std::list<Particle> particles;
    std::list<Particle>::iterator particle_iter;

    void update() {
        for(particle_iter = particles.begin(); particle_iter != particles.end(); ) {
            auto to_call = particle_iter++;
            to_call->update(*this);
        }
    }

    template<class Condition>
    void filter(Condition condition) {
        for(auto i = particles.begin(); i != particles.end();) {
            auto to_remove = i++;
            if(condition(*to_remove)) {
                // Remove the element.
                if(particle_iter == to_remove)
                    particle_iter = i;
                particles.erase(to_remove);
            }
        }
    }
};

void Particle::update(Explosion& explosion) {
    explosion.filter([this](Particle& other) { return this == &other; });
    // The above ends up destroying this object.
    // Cannot no longer access this and should only return.
}

int main() {
    Explosion explosion{{Particle{}, Particle{}}, {}};
    std::cout << explosion.particles.size() << '\n';
    explosion.update();
    std::cout << explosion.particles.size() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @George It keeps the iterator from invalidating.

Comment: @user463035818 Obviously.

Comment: maybe not obvious to OP ;)

Comment: Looks a good solution. But the problem is I have one more function render 
This is a lifecycle hook that is called after update lifecycle hook.

void Explosion::Render(Graphics *graphics) const {
 for (auto pIt = this->particles.begin(); pIt != this->particles.end(); pIt++) {
  (*pIt)->Render(graphics);
 }
}

So I can't use member iterator variables

Comment: @AshutoshRautela It is not clear why you cannot use member variables. May be you want to add these details and code to your question.

Comment: @AshutoshRautela Added an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the deleting of the element happens inside the `Update()` function and the "list" is actually `std::list` and not a `std::vector`.

Do not perform `pIt++` in the loop header. Instead, do `pIt++` BEFORE calling `Update()`.  Call `Update()` on the original object that is returned:

```
for (auto pIt = this->particles.begin(); pIt != this->particles.end(); ) {
    auto pForCall = *(pIt++);
    pForCall->Update(system, gameTime);
}
```

Another case where this will not work is when the element being delete is not the element we're calling `Update` on.

Comment: How will this gonna help ?

Comment: @AshutoshRautela it post-increments the iterator, returning the value being referred to *before* the iterator was incremented.  When `Update()` is then called, even if it removes the element that was at the original iterator position, the current iterator is not invalidated, so the loop will not malfunction

Comment: Ok. But the problem is the deletion is not happening via update function. It happens on a random time interval event. Basically the removal code is on another function which is called at an event.

Comment: @AshutoshRautela if that event is handled INSIDE of `Update()`, this approach avoids `Update()` invalidating the loop. If not, then the only way the event could interfer with the loop is if the event is running in *parallel* to the loop, in another thread or interrupt, in which case you must synchronize access to your list to avoid concurrent access.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your solution definitely solves the case when the deletion is inside update, in that case you are saving you iterator in the current loop from getting invalidated. 
The first loop I have mentioned is getting called in an application in an infinite loop, basically it's running in a game loop ok. And the particles die at random intervals, so the dead particles get deleted from the container once they die. Hope I am able to explain the context better

Comment: @AshutoshRautela an alternative solution would be to simply mark the particles when they die without actually removing them yet, then don't render dead particles in your render loop, and periodically remove marked particles from the list when it is safe to do so when nothing else is touching the list.